# There has been a critical error on your website. Learn more about debugging in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web, web-deployment, buddypress

I have installed buddypress follow plugin and after clicking the follow button , it shows the following error "There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress."

Comment: Readers will need more information in order to be able to help you effectively. Check your PHP or Apache logs to see if there is more information in there.

Answer (score 0):

set WP_DEBUG to true, which will be available in your wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```